# Integrated Dell Latitude Camera blinking (flashing) and black and white on all applications

Tags: drivers, usb, graphics, dell, webcam

My integrated camera works but blink/flash (like if I am dancing on a disco..) and displays only B/W images.

This is independent of the application, e.g. on Skype, Cheese, etc.

I'm on a Dell Latitude 5290 with Ubuntu 18.04

sudo lshw:

> ```
> [...]
> description: Detachable
> product: Latitude 5290 2-in-1 (081D)
> vendor: Dell Inc.
> serial: BK4BJR2
> width: 64 bits
> capabilities: smbios-3.1 dmi-3.1 smp vsyscall32
> configuration: boot=normal chassis=docking family=Latitude sku=081D uuid=44454C4C-4B00-1034-8042-C2C04F4A5232
> [...]
>           *-usb:1
>                description: Video
>                product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
>                vendor: CNFGE16O39442000DBB0
>                physical id: 5
>                bus info: usb@1:5
>                version: 70.05
>                serial: 0001
>                capabilities: usb-2.01
>                configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
> [...]
> ```

Any idea what could I do to make it working ?

Comment: I have the same problem when using skype.